# Range Hood - external blower: Is the design different?

Tags: blower, hood

I'm looking into installing a range hood. I'd like to install the motor in the next room, right on/in the wall that has the exhaust port. There are many companies offering external motor/rotor combinations for this exact purpose, but they always seem to cost about what a cheaper range hood with internal motor would cost, even when only in the 500m³/h range. A blower from a usual hood will produce about 400-900Pa pressure stoppered, or 600-1000m³/h flow, free blowing. Every design i saw (internal and external blower) was a radial rotor setup.

My question: I there a difference between the design for suction (as an external motor mainly needs to produce) vs. the design for pressure (as an internal motor mainly needs to produce) - or could i remove the motor from an internal design and just house it and install it externally? Is suction more difficult to produce and therefore more expensive, or are the products on the market just more rare and thus more expensive?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, there is no difference between ‘pressure’ and ‘suction’. To point you in the right direction, get that blower outside the house in its own little vibration insulated metal shed. Roof or wall is fine. The main issue is noise. If you ever want to both cook and have a conversation at the same time, heed this advice. I have installed both types and I will never install an in-hood blower again.

Comment: The noise is based on the fan rating, you can purchase fans that are whisper quiet yes these cost more and really high end ones all you hear is the air movement. There are different designs of fans like the normal propeller blade fans and squirl cage fans, the squirl cage fans I have found in high end models are directional . The air intake is through the large opening at the end of the squirl cage the exhaust is on the side of the housing around the cage.